# Python Code store a group of names in a list and count the number of words with an E in it

Tags: python, find

I want to accept a group of names and then store them in a list. Next, I want to count each name that has an "e" or "E" in it.This is what I have written thus far.

main()

Comment: def count_contain_e():
    Middle_Name=[]
    count=0
    for e in range (0,16):
        name=input("Enter your middle name")
        f=str("e")
        t=str("E")
        index=name.find(f)
        index2=name.find(t)
        if index==1 or index2==1:
            count=count+1
        print (count)
        Middle_Name.append(name)
      
    for e in Middle_Name:
        print(e)   
   
def main():
    count_contain_e()

main()

Comment: Please improve your question by editing it with your code, not putting the code in a comment, and asking a specific question about the trouble you are having with your code.As written, it's unclear what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Forgot you asked for user input instead of programmed list of names

This is a simple program that does what you're asking.

```
names = []
for i in range(16):
    name = input("Enter a name:")
    names.append(name)


def find_e(names):
    i = 0
    for name in names:
        if 'e' in name or 'E' in name:
            i += 1

    return i


print(find_e(names))
```